# Reuse std::stringstream and std::istream_iterator in loop

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following text file:

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 3 4 2 1 2 1
0 0 0 0 2 7 5 4 5 7 5 4 3
3 2 4 6 2 7 2 7 5 4 5 7 5 4 3
3 2 4 6 2 7 2 7 5 4  5 4 3
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 3 4 2 1 2 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 3 4 2 1 2 1
0 0 0 0 2 1 2 1
3 2 4 6 2 7 2 7 5 4 5 7 5 4 3
3 2 4 6 2 0 2 3 4 2 1 2 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 3 4 2 1 2 1
3 2 4 6 2 7 2 7 5 4 5 7 5 4 3
```

I can read it with the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream is("numbers.txt");
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> numbers{};
    while (std::getline(is,line)) {
        std::stringstream ss{line};
        std::istream_iterator<int> start{ss},end;
        numbers.emplace_back(start,end);
        std::cout << "Read " << numbers.back().size() << " numbers in row\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Read " << numbers.size() << " rows\n";

    std::cout << "numbers read in:\n";
    for (auto row : numbers) {
        for (auto number : row) {
            std::cout << number << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I would like to create the `std::stringstream` and `std::istream_iterator` only once outside the loop. How could I adjust the iterator to the correct position each time the loop executes in the following program?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream is("numbers.txt");
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> numbers{};
    std::stringstream ss{line};
    std::istream_iterator<int> start{ss},end;
    while (std::getline(is,line)) {
        ss << line;
        //start = ss.beg;
        numbers.emplace_back(start,end);
        std::cout << "Read " << numbers.back().size() << " numbers in row\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Read " << numbers.size() << " rows\n";

    std::cout << "numbers read in:\n";
    for (auto row : numbers) {
        for (auto number : row) {
            std::cout << number << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: _"I would like to create the std::stringstream and std::istream_iterator only once outside the loop."_ Why actually? Sounds like a XY-problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the second approach work two items must be addressed:

1. The `std::stringstream` `ss` must have the `eof` flag cleared so that it can be used again. For this we can use `ss.clear()`.
2. Then once new data has been added to `ss` the `std::istream_iterator` must be reset so that it can see the new input from the `std::stringstream`. The key here is to realize that as soon as it is constructed the iterator reads the first value it will provide.

So then the program becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream is("numbers.txt");
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> numbers{};
    std::stringstream ss{line};
    std::istream_iterator<int> start{ss},end;
    while (std::getline(is,line)) {
        ss.clear(); // clear eof flag
        ss << line; // ok to add data 
        start = ss; // reset the iterator so that it will see the new data
        numbers.emplace_back(start,end);
        std::cout << "Read " << numbers.back().size() << " numbers in row\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Read " << numbers.size() << " rows\n";

    std::cout << "numbers read in:\n";
    for (auto row : numbers) {
        for (auto number : row) {
            std::cout << number << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

In Visual Studio 2015 I did the following:

- I ran the two versions of the program with lots of entries and there
  is no noticeable difference.
- In both cases most of the time is spent constructing the iterator
  because the statement `start = ss;` seems to be calling the
  constructor in any case.